# Multidimensional Vector wouldn't let me remove an item

Tags: android, c++, vector

I am using this definition of a multidimensional vector:

```
Vector<Vector<sp<InputWindowHandle> > > mWindowHandles;
```

It works fine almost everywhere in the code except in this line:

```
(mWindowHandles[displayId]).removeAt(i--);
```

I don't understand why. Isn't a single entry of Vector should be a vector?
This is the compiling error I am getting:

> passing 'const android::Vector >' as 'this' argument of 'ssize_t android::Vector::removeAt(size_t) [with TYPE =
>   android::sp]' discards qualifiers

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you in a `const` method or is the variable `const` by any chance?

Comment: What Luchian said, `passing const ... as this ... discards qualifiers`

Comment: Perhaps an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would help then.

Comment: I'll try that (though I think this code is pretty simple already)

Comment: Looks like the inner `Vector` is being treated as const. Not familiar with Android SDK but you should check the exact specification of `operator[]` for class `Vector` - if it's the same as STL (i.e. non-const) then either your variable or function is const.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot @Component 10
Seems like the implementation of a Vector in android is different than the normal std::vector I am used to.
In order to remove an item, I had to do this:

`Vector<sp<InputWindowHandle> >& oneDisplayWindowHandles = mWindowHandles.editItemAt(displayId);`
`oneDisplayWindowHandles.removeAt(i--);`